# Download Image Using HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I am having trouble downloading an image of a website. I am using html2canvas from: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas and standard HTML, CSS, and javascript to add to the website. I attempted to use the standard HTML code for downloads (
link text) but it doesn't seem to work for what I was trying to do. I also tried the suggestions here: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/415/how-to-create-a-screenshot-of-your-website-with-javascript-using-html2canvas and on a few other websites as well, but I was unable to find the correct code to make it work. 
I can get the image of the webpage to append to the end of my current page with the code below:

```
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas); });
}
```

How can I edit the above code in order to download the web page as opposed to appending it?

Answer (score 2):

First, inject the html2canvas library into the webpage:

```
function injectScript(uri) {
    const document = window.document;
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", uri);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function injectHtml2canvas() {
    injectScript("//html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js");
}

injectHtml2canvas();
```

After the script has been loaded, call the library function to save the screenshot:

```
function saveScreenshot(canvas) {
    const fileName = "image";
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = fileName + ".png";
    console.log(canvas);
    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
        console.log(blob);
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.click();
    });
}

html2canvas(document.body, {
    allowTaint: true,
    useCORS: true
}).then(saveScreenshot);
```

Also see the FAQ on images:

> **Why aren't my images rendered?**
>
> html2canvas does not get around content policy restrictions set by your browser. Drawing images that reside outside of the origin of the current page taint the canvas that they are drawn upon. If the canvas gets tainted, it cannot be read anymore. As such, html2canvas implements methods to check whether an image would taint the canvas before applying it. If you have set the allowTaint option to false, it will not draw the image.
>
> If you wish to load images that reside outside of your pages origin, you can use a proxy to load the images.

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq/

Comment: This was quite helpful. I had to slightly tweak a few lines and got it to work overall. Thank you.