# Convert html to Image and Download

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to convert every message that is received into an image, and with the download button download it. every post is different

This is my .js code

```
// fetch Messages
           function fetchData() {
            $('#displayMessages').html('<div class="alert alert-info">Stiamo recuperando i tuoi messaggi!...</div>');
            $('#messages').click();
             $.ajax({
              url: 'controller/fetch_comments.php',

              //success
               success: function(data){

         if (data=='please login') {
          window.location='./';
          console.log(data);
         }
         else{

          var $fetch ='';
          var component ='';


         
          if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(data.replace(/\\["\\\/bfnrtu]/g, '@').
replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, ']').
replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, ''))) {
            data=JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(data);

           $.each(data, function(i, fetchAll){
            var fetchData= data[i];
            let message_title = fetchData.message_title ?? ""
  $fetch += '<div class="row m-0"> <div class="pull-left alert col-md-2 mb-0"><img src="assets/img/anon.jpg" style=" width: 50px; height: 50px;  border-radius:50%; box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); border: 5px solid #2c2c2c;" class="m-0"></div> <div class="alert col-md-7 m-0" style="margin-left:0px; color:#2c2c2c;"> <b>'  +message_title +'</b><br>'  +fetchData.description
         +'</div> <div class="col-md-3 alert pull-right m-0"><span style="color: black;" class="fa fa-clock m-0"></span><br><text style="color: black; font-size:10px;"> ';
         $fetch+=fetchData.date_created+'</text></div></div>';

        });

          } else {

            $fetch +='<div class="alert alert-danger">Ancora nessun messaggio </div>';
          console.log(fetch);
          $('#displayMessages').html($fetch)
         }

        $('#displayMessages').html($fetch);
             }

           }

           });

}
```

this is the php code

```
$usersObj = new Comments();

$logsObj = new Logs();



    $id = isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : 1;

    if (empty($id)) {

        exit();

    }



    if ($allComments = $usersObj ->FETCH_COMMENTS($id)) {

        $logDescription = 'data fetched!';

        $logsObj->INSERT_LOG($id, $logDescription);



    }else{

        echo 'log failed';



    }

   echo isset($allComments) ? json_encode($allComments) : 'nothing found';
```

This is my html in my dashboard, is used to show the message

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">



                      <div id="displayMessages">
                      </div>

                       


                    </div>
```

I don't understand where I have to act, thanks for the help feel free to edit the code

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as a oneliner in javascript.

Just by using the library [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/getting-started).

e.g.

html:

```
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
</div>
```

js:

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```

put the image into an a tag with the propertie of "download".

I hope i could help you out.

EDIT:
In your html file add the cdn as following to the head:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas
/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

then in your js file

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");
    const a_tag = document.createElement("a"); //just create an a tag
    a_tag.innerHTML = "download"; //this text is displayed
    a_tag.download = "image.png"; //pictures will download as image.png - you can customize the name and file format, but not all formats are acceptet in html2canvas
    body.appendChild(a_tag); //append the a tag to the body element, you will need to customize this for your needs
    html2canvas(document.querySelector(".wrapper")).then((canvas) => {
      canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob); //creates location of image
        a_tag.href = url; //append url to a tags href
      });
    });
```

You will need this for every Message you receive. After your messages are displayed in the dom as html, the "html2canvas" will create an image out of that. In the "toBlob" function the image is just cached but not showing anywhere. We link the blob url (location of the cached image) to the a tags href. So if we then click on it, it will download. The .wrapper in the html2canvas function i've selected should be your message-div

Comment: Can you help me in doing this?

Comment: @Lorenzo i've found a similar question with a big answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839453/download-image-using-html2canvas hopefully this will help you. Otherwise the documentation of html2canvas, which ive linked earlier would also help you alot.

Comment: my question is if I have to act on dashboard.html or on the js file

Comment: You need to act in your js file - because html2canvas is a js-library. You can directly convert the html messages, which you get in your js file, to pictures and show them on your page instead of your html message.

Comment: @TrueStoyShort I can't, another help?

Comment: @Lorenzo i've made an edit. The code i've provided you will need for every message. So under every html-message which is displayed in your dashboard will have the a tag which then redirects you to the blob-url and download the html-message as an image.

Comment: @TrueStoyShort this makes me a screenshot of the general page, I need to extract only the message, so https://imgur.com/Rrrn6lQ